# html or css with jquery succint

Tags: jquery, html, css

On the recommendation of someone on stackoverflow, I used jquery succint https://github.com/micjamking/Succinct to truncate my posts on a php site.

It works perfectly however, I encountered a small issue (for me)... I changed the elipses to custom text saying "Read More" like this

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.mypost a').succinct({
            omission: '...Read More'
        });
    });
</script>
```

That would be perfect, but I want to wrap the "Read More" that succint adds on the truncated text with a span tag.

Currently if I wrap it in a span it renders the whole span html as text. The simple effect I am trying to achieve is to make the "Read More" text a different color then the ".mypost a" text that it is truncating.

if I can wrap it in a span, I can add the css .mypost a span {color:#f00;}

And get the desired outcome.

Does anyone have a suggest to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the README.md from the site, it appears as if you can just change the `omission` to be the required HTML: `omission: '...<span class="mypost">Read More</span>'`

Alternatively you can just use CSS to do this:

```
.mypost {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That would seem like an obvious way, if that worked. I tried that first before posting here. When I add that, it just renders it right in page `<span>Read More</span>` So, it actually displays it as text, I am trying to figure out how to not show that and actually have my Read More text wrapped in a span tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Line 46 of jQuery.succinct.js](https://github.com/micjamking/succinct/blob/master/jQuery.succinct.js#L46) it is obvious that it is using the [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to replace the text of the element being truncated so any text will be HTML encoded when replaced. If you want to continue using this library you can fork it and modify it to accept HTML for the replacement text, or find another library.